# HTML/Javascript show data on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby, layout

I want to put some text on an image dynamically.

Setup:

- I want to make a dynamic layout of my network and show it in a webpage. On this image / layout, I want to put the IP addresses on the scheme.

Languages used:

- Ruby, Sinatra (webframework for ruby)
- HTML(5)
- JQuery

Are there any API's or frameworks providing this functionality on a website?

Comment: I would reommend to put a layer over the image with the ip in it via css. So you dont have to modofie the image. Additionally the ip would be copyable

Comment: And the code that you have tried is?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't have code, because I have no idea of there is even a framework out there (I did search, but no good result). Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="network_box">
    <img src="network.jpg">
    <span class="text_data" id="ip_1">
        0.0.0.0:3000
    </span>
    <span class="text_data" id="ip_2">
        0.0.0.0:4000
    </span>
    <span class="text_data" id="ip_3">
        0.0.0.0:3000
    </span>
    <span class="text_data" id="ip_4">
        0.0.0.0:3000
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.network_box{
width: 700px;
height: 400px;
position: relative; 
}
.network_box img {
width: 700px;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 10
}

.network_box .text_data{
position: absolute;
z-index: 20 
}

#ip_1{
top: 10px;
left: 15px  
}

#ip_2{
top: 50px;
left: 155px 
}
```

just use use ID to set correct position(from left top corner of block)

Comment: This is a good solution to put the IP addresses on the image. I've looked at possibilities to make the scheme itself and I found some diagram-generators that perhaps could do the trick. If I'll try to combine your CSS solution (via JQuery) and see if I can get somewhere :) Thx!

Comment: np) also you can set elem position directly via html "data" attribute. then just loop throw all elements with .text_data class take that atributes and set according style. example  ` <div class="text_data" data-top="100" data-left="123">123.12.124</div>`. via jquery: $('.text_data').data('left');